# Facebook OAuth login - ID or email

Tags: facebook, email, facebook-graph-api, oauth, identification

I'd like to offer our users a Facebook login option. But I'm not sure how to identify existing users (without a stored Facebook ID).

From the docs:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/multiple-providers#addingfacebook

> After a successful login using Facebook, you will have the person's
>   email address, Facebook ID, and access token. Your **app should search
>   for an existing account that has been created with that same email
>   address**. If one exists, you should merge the two accounts and add
>   the Facebook info to the existing account - as recommended above.

That doesn't sound like a secure approach to me. What would prevent someone from creating a new Facebook account with a fake email address that matches a user account in my app and then use my Facebook login option? (Obviously, this will not work if the user already owns a Facebook account)

Comment: The API only returns a user’s email address, if it has been verified – so the user needs access to the inbox of the email account.

Comment: Oh, I completely forgot that Facebook requires email verification. Now it makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: @netrooo What about making an answer, with a link to the FB docs that says emails are always verified? I'd upvote it :- )

Answer (score 0):

Your concern...

> That doesn't sound like a secure approach to me. What would prevent someone from creating a new Facebook account with a fake email address that matches a user account in my app and then use my Facebook login option? (Obviously, this will not work if the user already owns a Facebook account)

TL;DR

**Facebook Registration process**

1. Go to facebook.com/reg.
2. Enter the name you go by in everyday life.
3. Enter your **email or mobile phone number**.

**So...**

> Facebook needs your email or phone number, that means there's no way someone can use another account's email or phone number to sign up again.

**My advice to you is...**

1. You have two or more authentication methods - **1 manual** (email & pass) | **the rest** (social login).
2. You already have users, so when users login using OAuth and a matching email or phone number is found, you ask permission to link their Facebook account to your app or site account with a matching credential.
3. At this point you should authenticate the persons identity one last time, by having them enter the password for their account on your app or site.
4. Now you can safely assume this person is who they say they are and store their info in your DB.